# Automation of networks using ansible on openstack

Tags: linux, shell, ansible, openstack

I've written an ansible script, to create a network based on a condition. So that, even if I run ansible script again it will not create duplicate entries in my openstack environment.

task:

```
name: "create network"

shell: neutron net-create (openstack details like project username,password, api) network_1

when: ("neutron net-list -c name| grep network_1| awk '{print$2}'" == "null")
  the above condition didn't work so, I tried another condition

when: ("neutron net-list -c name| grep network_1| awk '{print$2}'" == neutron net-list -c name| grep network_2 | awk '{print$2}')
```

I don't have either of  the twonetworks in my project.  My intention was, both the statments display null output and firsttime condition becomes true and it should execute and create a network. If I run the script for second time it not satify condition and condition check becomes false and network will not be created.

But both the conditions skipped and returned false saying condition check failed.

Comment: Do these `neutron` command lines work if you copy/paste them and execute them in a standard terminal? You need to be certain they are returning what your condtional's are expecting. It might help non-neutron readers if you include sample output for those commands. Good luck.

Comment: hey shellter, they do not return anything. As they are non-existing in the table. Condition is if they return null or nothing command should execute  . It looks like I need to find another way around. Thank you though for looking into it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your when condition needs to be something that Ansible will recognise and not just a shell command that you haven't told it how to execute.

In this case you could do something like this:

```
- name: check for network_1    
  shell: "neutron net-list -c name| grep network_1| awk '{print$2}'"    
  register: network_1

- name: "create network"    
  shell: neutron net-create (openstack details like project username,password, api) network_1    
  when: network_1.stdout == "null"
```

That's presuming that when you run `neutron net-list -c name| grep network_1| awk '{print$2}'` when network_1 doesn't exist it returns `null` (I haven't used OpenStack much so not sure if this is in fact true).

In general though, with Ansible you should only be shelling out if you absolutely need to because then you need to do things like above where you need to check for existence of resources and manage idempotency which should be covered for you by any decent module. In this case you should be able to use [`os_network`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/os_network_module.html) to create your network if it doesn't already exist:

```
- os_network:
    cloud: mycloud
    state: present
    name: network_1
    external: false
```

It will also happily pick up environment variables such as `OS_USERNAME` on the host running Ansible so you can avoid putting credentials in to your Ansible code.

Comment: You'd have to edit your question to add the output of a command that checks whether the network is there with both a negative and a positive result

Comment: I've tried using os_network module, but overhead with it is, you need to install shade module on the host which you're running. for that first we need to install pip, then using pip we need to install shade and virtualenv etc. Shade module is installing python packages related to keystone nova etc. Am little concerned if those package modifying openstack components make some damage. I've tried to change the question as u suggested. but couldn't find it. new to stack flow.

Answer (score 0):

- name: network list

  shell: neutron net-list -c name | grep network | awk '{print$2}'

  register: res
- name: network create

  shell: neutron net-create network

  when: res.stdout != "network"

Here in first statement am checking if the network name is present in the list. Second section am saying if network name is not equal to network, create the network. If we run the playbook again this condition will be false as the first statement will be able to retrieve the name from table. Thanks.